# tooltips in angular-stack freezing

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

i have created a couple of tool tips using angular strap + angular animate(angular motion). Initially they are working since all of then are displaying on hover. But when quickly hovering over any of the tool tips, they freeze and get stuck in the top left corner.

```
nav(id="menubarContainer")

    ul
        li(bs-tooltip="tooltip.home"  data-placement="bottom")
            i(class="fa fa-home fa-2x" ui-sref="home")

        li(bs-tooltip="tooltip.create" data-placement="bottom-left")
            i(class="fa fa-plus fa-2x")

        li(bs-tooltip="tooltip.settings" data-placement="bottom-left")
            i(class="fa fa-cog fa-2x")

        li(bs-tooltip="tooltip.help" data-placement="bottom-left")
            i(class="fa fa-question-circle fa-2x")
```

chrome shoes this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null angular-animate.js:290

which is this:

```
 function extractElementNode(element) {
      for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) { //here it cant read length of null!
        var elm = element[i];
        if(elm.nodeType == ELEMENT_NODE) {
          return elm;
        }
      }
    }
```

anyone have any similare issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a regression bug. You need to go back to version 1.2.13 of Angular and ngAnimate. There is no bug fix yet. Sorry :(

For further details you can watch this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6592).

Comment: No problem, i ended up just needing simple tool tips and created a directive to do this.